# vb.net matching textbox.text with contents of listbox data

Tags: vb.net

What I want to do is type a number in textbox1 and then match the word that corresponds to it for example

```
if textbox1.text = 6
then textbox2.text = searchable
```

but this list could be 10000 items long, so don't want to hard code it.

listbox contains the following data.I am open to changing the layout slightly if needed.

```
1 example
2 word
3 to 
4 find
5 by
6 searchable
7 numbers
```

then upon button2 click my textbox2 would contain searchable (but not the number)

Thanks

Comment: isnt a combobox a textbox which is linked to a listbox?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your button's click event

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Val(TextBox1.Text) <= ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then '<--- check the textbox contains a number less than the item count of the list box
        TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.Items(TextBox1.Text) '<---- replace the number with carasponding item in the listbox
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `Listbox.Findstring(textbox1.text.trim & " ")` or `Listbox.FindString(Val(TextBox1.Text))`

These return the index to the item you are looking for...

Comment: This only returns a number, not the correct number or the word that I need im afraid       Listbox.FindString(Val(TextBox1.Text))

Comment: the index of the item might not always match the free text number in textbox1 though if I understand correctly. the listbox may not have the numbers in sequence.